# SSH-Server Library for Android

Tags: java, android, ssh, jsch

for a project I need a possibility to log in into a bash on an android device over the internet. 
At first I thought about ADB over TCPIP, but from what I read it doesn't seem like a secure solution.

The first alternative that came to my mind was SSH. I know that there are many Apps out there which can host a SSH-Server, but I need a solution in an own app, because I would need more control over that server.
So the go-to solution would be an own SSH-Server via a library.

As far as I understand, libraries like [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) are just for connecting to other servers, but not for hosting them.

Is there any open-source library, that can host a SSH-Server and supports Password-Auth? (Some Apps son't support that)

Or is there another alternative path to the solution of that problem?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Only the last paragraph is "valid". Asking for libraries is explicitly off topic here. Having said that: what problems do you intend to solve with such an app? Me personally, I would never ever install an app that opens an ssh server on my mobile. That just screams "security breach" (and it would not surprise me if the android policies forbid to that, too)

Comment: Thank you for the hint regarding the off-topic-part. I'll edit that.

The solution is not intended for public use, it is intended for only a small, restricted userbase.
All in all I need to be able to maintain and service special android devices remotely. Therefore I need some way to have complete control over the device even if I am not on site.

Comment: You should probably investigate [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the updates by the OP, the answer is: you are going down the wrong rabbit hole.

A simple app can't just open a ssh server, and allow you to take full control from remote.

You rather have to design a real MDM solution, for example relying on the Samsung Knox technology. But of course, knox only exists for Samsung devices.

A truly robust solution to control arbitrary Android devices is a very advanced undertaking.

A starting point with more information:

https://www.zdnet.com/article/mdm-for-android-devices-what-your-business-needs-to-know/

Given the specific requirements of the OP, the answer might be to install a "regular" ssh server, such as dropbear. When all the devices are rooted anyway, why not simply add a ssh server by itself, relying on a unified password for example. See here for a list of products:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9905/is-there-some-ssh-server-for-android

Comment: I don't think, that a MDM solution is the right thing for that usecase. The devices the end-users use are rooted and heavily modified.
I am looking for a way to update things remotely on a system-level. It is not just about installing apps or wiping the device remotely, it is more or less about a way to be able to service the device as if I was connected via ADB.

Comment: I get your point. But thing is that answers here are not only written for the actual questioner, but any future readers. Nonetheless I will think about this and enhance it in case I figure a solution for your very specific requirements.

Comment: Thing is, that I don't have full control over "regular" ssh-servers like the one listed in the StackExchange-Link you provided.
If I use a ssh-server I think it would be better If it would be not a ready-to-use one, rather just a library I can use in an own app.

Comment: What you are doing is like 200 percent out of the recommended ordinary anyway. There aren't many people that need what you are looking for. So, at some point you probably have to compromise. Because without broad demand, option space is most often pretty limited.

Comment: Yea I already was afraid that that point would come.

Would it be a (secure) solution to use ADB over TCPIP and just block all Internet Access via iptables that is not needed for the functionality of the device except one server that I can use to connect to the device?

Comment: Just a small idea: What If I developed an app that just connects via a custom websocket to a server of my choosing, gets from that server instructions or commands, and then just parses these commands to the internal android-shell?
Of course that would mean some extra work, but it should solve all mentioned problems, right?

Comment: Please understand: this is not how this community works. This is not a discussion forum where people work jointly to solve problems. Coming back with more questions in comments isn't a good idea. Rather consider rewording / enhancing your question instead.